# ValueError RL Gym Environment in Jupyter Notebook, but working on Colab

Tags: python, anaconda, google-colaboratory, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I made a custom environment on gym. Now I am training a PPO Agent, but an error occurs when I run the model.learn code. This error:

*ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (4,) + inhomogeneous part.
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...*

**The thing is that this error does not occur on Colab, and I dont know why. I have uninstalled and installed anaconda and visual studio code, trying with different environments but the error still remains.**

I would appreciate if someone has the solution. Thanks in advance.